# pyinstall not working with option --noconsole

Tags: python, pyinstaller

When a use pyinstaller on python file without the --windowed or --noconsole option it works fine, but when i do it gives this error.

```
 Failed to execute script
```

Here's my python code:

```
 import subprocess
 sb = subprocess.run('dir',shell=True, stdin=None, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
 stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
 print(sb.stdout + sb.stderr)
```

Pyinstaller command:

```
  pyinstaller -F --windowed script.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered how to solve it

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(conn, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL, shell=True)
stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
print(stdout + stderr)
```

it looks live i had to set stdin to subprocess.DEVNULL, im not really sure why but it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

When using PyInstaller in windowed mode, you need to handle `stdin`:

```
import subprocess
sb = subprocess.run('dir', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
print(sb.stdout + sb.stderr)
```

Comment: thank you for the try, but i already solved it using Popen and it works